# Query is Slow when using cross apply column in where cause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query. Every row in tblSMSSendQueueMain may have some record in tblSMSSendQueueMainSendStatus. QueueID in tblSMSSendQueueMainSendStatus is foreign key for ID in tblSMSSendQueueMain

```
select top 10 ID from tblSMSSendQueueMain q
CROSS Apply
(
    select top 1 SendStatus from tblSMSSendQueueMainSendStatus where QueueID = q.ID order by ID desc
) qs
where qs.SendStatus = 1 order by ID Desc
```

This query take a long time to run. But if I write `qs.SendStatus = 5` its fast.

I have nonclustered index on tblSMSSendQueueMainSendStatus as below

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblSMSSendQueueMainSendStatus_SendStatus] ON [dbo].[tblSMSSendQueueMainSendStatus]
(
    [QueueID] ASC,
    [ID] DESC
)
INCLUDE([SendStatus]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Whats wrong? Or is there is a better way to write this query, joining multi tables values and filter the result.

Thanks

Comment: I would guess that `status = 1` returns lots and lots of rows, whereas `status = 5` only returns a few.

Comment: i'm agree with you but i dont know what should i do when status is 1 and result is a lot

Comment: Pushing the `WHERE` inside the `CROSS APPLY` would help probably, as would changing the index to `QueueID, SendStatus`. Please share query plans of the different options via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: `cross apply` is the wrong syntax to use here, suggest this is just an `exists` criteria?

Comment: I used cross apply because every ID in parent table may have more than 1 related rows in the child table, but just need to get the last row of child table

Comment: Is this representative of your actual query since you are only selecting ID which exists in both tables?

Comment: Yes im selecting ID, but just ids that their last send status are 1

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have your execution plans. I am just providing an alternative way of INNER JOIN. Test your query for performance.

```sql
;WITH CTE_QueueStatus AS
(
select q.ID, qs.SendStatus, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY qs.QueueID ORDER BY qs.ID desc)  as rnk from tblSMSSendQueueMain q
INNER JOIN tblSMSSendQueueMainSendStatus qs ON  qs.QueueID = q.ID
)
SELECT top 10 ID 
FROM CTE_QueueStatus AS c
where qs.SendStatus = 1 -- only sendstatus =1 is selected
and c.rnk = 1 -- Only the top status is selected
order by ID Desc
```

Comment: I doubt this would improve performance.  Do you have a reason why you think it would?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, As I dont have execution plans. I just provided an alternative. I will update my post. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Venkataraman R
there are millions of rows in tblSMSSendQueueMainSendStatus  and tblSMSSendQueueMain, your solution didnt work